# OpenGL texture not displaying despite setting uniform int

Tags: opengl, c++, macos

As you can see in the linked image, despite assigning a texture unit, there is no texture being drawn on the screen.
In the main loop, I am receiving error 1282, and there are no further errors throughout the code, I have checked with sporadic calls to the error checking function.

I am using an M2 Mac, could that be a root cause?

[image]

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>  // GLAD helper library for OpenGL function pointer help
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // GLFW helper library for window management
#include <iostream>
#include "shaders/Shader.h"
#include "Textures/Texture.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "ext/stb_image.h"


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

/* Default screen size values */
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;

int main() {

    /* configure window and set glfw/opengl settings */
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // macOS specific apparently?

    /* create window object */
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Learn-OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* init GLAD before using any opengl functions */
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {  // OS specific location of function pointers
        std::cout << "Failed to init GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    /* init viewport prior to rendering -> makes it so screen coords work */
    glViewport(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);     // separate to GLFW window size so make them equal!

    /* callback to allow for user window resizing */
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    /* Set up our shader */
    Shader shader("shaders/vertexShading.glsl", "shaders/fragmentShading.glsl");

    /* Set up our texture */
    Texture texture("../res/container.jpg");

    /* Define x,y,z positions of each vertex on our vertices.
       Normalised device coords -> always between -1 and 1 */
    float vertices[] = {
            // positions          // colors           // texture coords
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f    // top left
    };


    /*  VBO holds the actual vertex data.
        VAO keeps track of how to use the vertex data from a VBO.
        EBO specifies the order in which the vertices should be connected to form shapes. */
    unsigned int VBOs[2], VAOs[2];
    glGenBuffers(2, VBOs);
    glGenVertexArrays(2, VAOs);

    /* vertices data */
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);

    /* copy vertex data into the buffer's memory */
    /* static draw since data is set once and used many times. Use dynamic if the data changes a lot */
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /* how we should interpret vertex data per vertex attribute */
    // position attr
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   // we set location as 0 in our shader code
    // color attr
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));   // offset of size 3 floats
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);   // we set location as 1 in our shader code
    // texture attr
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6*sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


    shader.use();
    shader.setUniformInt("ourTexture", 0);


    /* window loop */
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        // input -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        processInput(window);

        // rendering ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);   // greenish
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // clear colour buffer

        /* bind texture data */
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getID());
        

        shader.use();

        /* draw vertices */
        glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


        // unbind buffers ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // check and call events + swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window) {
    /* ability to close window */
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }

    /* ability to swap between fill and wireframe modes -> hold w key */
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    } else {
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    }
}
```

```cpp
//
// Created by Henry Fielding on 23/8/2023.
//

#include "Texture.h"

Texture::Texture(const char* fp) {
    /* load in texture file and set values */
    data = stbi_load(fp, &width, &height, &numChannels, 0);

    /* generate texture id */
    glGenTextures(1, &ID);

    /* bind it so any subsequent GL_TEXTURE_2D commands apply to it */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);

    /* configure texture wrapping and filtering options. changes behaviour view docs to see differences */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    /* ... actually generate the texture */
    if (data) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "FAILED TO LOAD TEXTURE" << std::endl;
    }

    /* free image data */
    stbi_image_free(data);
}

unsigned int Texture::getID() {
    return ID;
}
```

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

````
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you add .txt extension and try?

Like so:

`Shader shader("shaders/vertexShading.glsl.txt", "shaders/fragmentShading.glsl.txt");`

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your GPU drivers, also check to see if the openGL Mac lib is there and not missing.

*source (It's a minecraft error fix but theoretically should work for you):*
[https://gameserrors.com/minecraft-opengl-error-1282/#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20experiencing%20the,Errors%20option%20and%20keep%20playing](https://gameserrors.com/minecraft-opengl-error-1282/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20experiencing%20the,Errors%20option%20and%20keep%20playing).